# Sorting in named_scope through 2 tables with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel, meta-search

I am looking for solution how to sort by attribute which is two association levels deep and also have an condition.

I have order model which HAS TO have association with Shop model OR Warehouse model both of these models are associated with country which has a name.

### My goals are:

Scoped the orders and sort by country name.

Result has to be a ActiveRelation object

And the main goal is use this scope for MetaSearch gem for view helper sort_link

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :warehouse

  validate :shop_id, :presence => true,      :if => "warehouse_id.nil?"
  validate :warehouse_id, :presence => true, :if => "shop_id.nil?" 

  #the case with shop_id.present? && warehouse_id.present? does not exist 

  scope :sort_by_country_name, ???

end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end

class Warehouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end

Country.coulumn_names => [:id, :name, ...]
```

Actualy i dont know if this is  possible so I appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this, I have not tried it though:

```
scope :sort_by_warehouse_country_name, joins(:warehouse).order('warehouse.country_name DESC')
```

This is assuming that you have

```
delegate :name, to: :country, prefix: true
```

In WareHouse class.

EDIT:

Since you want to take in either warehouse country or shop country, you need a logic in select query to select the first non-null entry for country name. PostgreSQL and MySQL support function [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), which returns the first non-null column. You should be able to use it like this: (Again, have not tried it though)

```
def self.sort_by_country_name
    Order.select("COALESCE(warehouse.country_name, shop.country_name) as country_name").joins(:warehouse, :shop).order("country_name DESC")
end
```

Comment: Nice idea with using the delegate method but not sure if that works. However the problem is the order have warehouse or shop and you describe only the one case with warehouse. But not each order have warehouse.

Comment: I put warehouse here, because it is not clear from your question whether sorting orders by country means country of the warehouse or the country of the shop. You can do the same for shop also and sort orders accordingly.

Comment: Thats the problem I need scope both of these variants simultaneously. I should use something like UNION in sql i think.

Comment: You might have a tough time b/c Arel doesn't support ordering unions at present: https://github.com/rails/arel/issues/98. It's probably not worth it, but you could do the UNION in a view and move the relevant logic to that model, or define a scope in the Order model that uses a join of Orders to the bare model of the view, thereby keeping all the following logic in Order.